# SQL SERVER CURSOR VS CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, cursor

I have BatchDetail table as
[image: Batch Detail table]

For every row I want to check if the total value is negative and update a flag so that those rows wont be considered in further processing. I have taken the  approaches below

Take all rows whose total value is positive i.e rows with pid 1,3,5,6.

Use a cursor and one by one check with BatchDetail  to find corresponding negative total and update those rows.

This approach was taking too much time since batch_detail table has ten thousands rows. So after googling I decided to use CROSS APPLY wherein I had taken temp table with same column as batchDetail table plus new column as newPid , inserted rows with positive total and cross apply with batch detail table as:

```
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE  
SET TEMP_TABLE.NEWPID=TEMP.PID,TEMP_TABLE.FLAG=1 
FROM TEMP_TABLE T CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT * FROM BATCH_DETL_TBL 
 WHERE LOAN_NUMBER=T.LAON_NUMBER AND TOTAL=-T.TOTAL)) TEMP
```

[image: Result]

The problem is that once row with pid 3(total 50) matched with pid 4(total -50), pid 4 row should not match again with pid 5 row . So once rows with positve and negative amount is updated it should not consider for next set of rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tricky one. For each unique positive total, you have to order all records with that total, and independently order all records with the *negative* of that total, so that you can match them up. This ensures each record is only matched once.

Here's how it can be done, using your test data:

```
create table t1 (loan_number int, pid int, total int, newPid int, flag int );
insert into t1 (loan_number, pid, total ) values (411001,1,100), (411001,2,-100), (411001,3,50), (411001,4,-50), (411001,5,50), (411001,6,25);
update pos set newPid=neg.pid, flag=1 from
    ( select loan_number, pid, total, 
             row_number() over (partition by total order by pid) rn 
      from t1 
      where total>0) pos
    inner join 
    (select loan_number, pid, total, 
            row_number() over (partition by total order by pid) rn 
            from t1 
            where total<0) neg 
    on  neg.loan_number = pos.loan_number 
    and neg.total =- pos.total 
    and neg.rn = pos.rn
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `join`, but you need a sequence number for matching the `total`s:

```
UPDATE TEMP_TABLE
    SET TEMP_TABLE.NEWPID = TEMP.PID,
        TEMP_TABLE.FLAG = 1
    FROM (SELECT t.*,
                row_number() over (partition by total order by (select null)) as seqnum
          FROM TEMP_TABLE T
         ) t JOIN
         (SELECT dt.*,
                 row_number() over (partition by total order by (select null)) as seqnum
          FROM BATCH_DETL_TBL dt
         ) dt
         on dt.LOAN_NUMBER = T.LOAN_NUMBER AND
            dt.TOTAL = -T.TOTAL AND
            dt.seqnum = T.seqnum;
```

This should be much faster than a cursor (advice:  avoid cursors, unless you really have no alternative).  The `cross apply` and `join` should be similar in performance.  For performance, you can also add an index on `batch_detl_tbl(load_number, total)`.

Comment: I need to match seqnum before updating?

Comment: @user530158 . . . Yes, that would be the whole reason for adding that variable.  Thank you.